# Why does the lw instruction's second argument take in both an offset and regSource?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

So the lw instruction is in the following format: `lw RegDest, Offset(RegSource)`. Why does the second argument take in both an offset and register source? Why not only one (i.e. only register source)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because what else are you going to do with the rest of the 32-bit instruction word?  (Assuming you're the CPU architect designing the MIPS instruction set).

It lets **LUI + LW load from any arbitrary 32-bit address in 2 instructions, instead of 3**. And for loop unrolling or struct pointer->member access, avoiding ADDIU instructions for pointer math.  i.e. **spending that amount of coding space on LW/SW allows MIPS programs to be more efficient.**  Sometimes you only need `0($reg)`, but other times it would be a waste of instructions to compute the final address in a register.

Leaving out the 16-bit immediate displacement can't make the instruction shorter. MIPS is a RISC with fixed-length instruction words.  (It could be R-type instead of I-type, but you'd still have unused bits in that format.  Classic MIPS had lots of unused coding space, and spending coding space on LW/SW, LB/LBU/SB, and so on, is worth it.)

MIPS doesn't have a lot of different opcodes (especially classic MIPS without any FPU instructions, and without 64-bit instructions).  It uses a lot of the instruction coding space to support an immediate form for most instructions, with a large immediate.  (Unlike ARM32 for example which uses 4 bits in each instruction for predicated execution, and more bits for "flexible" source operand (optional rotate or shift by a constant or another register, or an immediate constant).  But ARM immediates are encoded as 8 bits with a rotation, allowing lots of useful bit patterns that are common in real life.)

---

**MIPS only has one addressing mode, and `imm16(reg)` can save a significant number of `addiu` instructions vs. just `(reg)`.**

For example, consider a C function that loads or stores to a static (or global) variable.  Like

```
unsigned rng(void) {
    static unsigned seed = 1234;
    return (seed = seed * 5678 + 0x1234);
}
```

The compiler-generated (or hand-written) asm needs to load and store from `seed`, so you need it in a register.  But it's a 32-bit constant that doesn't fit in a single instruction.  In hand-written asm you'd probably use a pseudo-instruction like `la $t0, rng.seed`, which will assemble to `lui $t0, hi(rng.seed)` / `ori $t0, $t0, lo(rng.seed)`.  (hi and lo get half of the 32-bit address).

But you can do better than that:

```
lui   $t0, hi(rng.seed)
lw    $t1, lo(rng.seed) ($t0)
```

i.e. use the low 16 bits of the address as the 16-bit displacement in the load instruction.  This is in fact what [compilers like gcc do](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'unsigned+rng(void)+%7B%0A++++static+unsigned+seed+%3D+1234%3B%0A++++return+(seed+%3D+seed+*+5678+%2B+0x1234)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:32.39601640304628,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips5,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'MIPS+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:34.27065026362039,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
rng:    # gcc5.4 -O3
    lui     $5,%hi(seed.1482)
    lw      $4,%lo(seed.1482)($5)
    nop                       ; classic MIPS has a 1-cycle "shadow" for loads before the result is usable, with no pipeline interlock
    sll     $3,$4,5          ; I should have picked a simpler multiply constant (with fewer bits set)
    sll     $2,$4,3
    subu    $2,$3,$2
    sll     $3,$2,3
    subu    $2,$3,$2
    subu    $2,$2,$4
    sll     $3,$2,4
    addu    $2,$2,$3
    sll     $2,$2,1
    addiu   $2,$2,4660
    j       $31
    sw      $2,%lo(seed.1482)($5)       ; branch-delay slot

seed.1482:
    .word   1234
```

There are lots of other uses for small immediate displacements from a register.  For example:

- accessing locals on the stack if the compiler spills anything
- `struct` fields
- Array access in an unrolled loop.  (MIPS has 32 integer registers, and is pretty much designed for software-pipelining to unroll loops).
- small compile-time constant array indices.

As I said, there isn't much else you could do with those extra 16 bits of the instruction word that would be a good fit for MIPS.  You could leave fewer than 16 bits for the displacement, but MIPS isn't PowerPC (where there are lots and lots of opcodes).

Comment: (Re: using fewer bits for immediates: RISC-V does that: 20 bits for LUI, 12 bits for other immediates.  Still plenty for loop unrolling and structs, but takes less opcode coding-space except for one opcode.)