# Query on various addressing modes?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Can an array be implemented using only indirect addressing mode? I think we can only access the first element but what about the other elements? For that, I think, we'll have to use immediate addressing mode.

Comment: An `add` instruction can generate an address in a register.  A CPU with only `[register]` addressing modes would work, but need more instructions than one with an immediate displacement as part of load/store instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes I was also thinking so. Kindly add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `add` instruction can generate an address in a register.

A CPU with only `[register]` addressing modes would work, but need more instructions than one with an immediate displacement as part of load/store instructions.

Instruction set design isn't about what's *necessary* for computation to be possible, but rather about how to make it *efficient*.

related:

- [Why does the lw instruction's second argument take in both an offset and regSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140313/why-does-the-lw-instructions-second-argument-take-in-both-an-offset-and-regsour)
- [What is the minimum instruction set required for any Assembly language to be considered useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439001/what-is-the-minimum-instruction-set-required-for-any-assembly-language-to-be-con/19677755#19677755) (note the difference between *useful* and *Turing-complete*.)